# Iphone App - Project Structure

Tags: iphone

I was wondering if anyone can give me some advice regarding the structure of my iphone app.  As a non programmer i've broken my app down into smaller projects, i.e. a project for each main function of my app (Twitter RSS Feed, 3rd Party API etc etc).  The idea being that i don't swamp myself with code whilst i'm trying to learn and i maintain the integrity of each function should things go belly up.  Once i'm happy with each project i'm going to stitch them together into the finished article.

My question is:  Is my method advisable or will i be making life difficult for myself come the end when i try and pull each project together or should i be starting off building my app into one project?

I'm very appreciative of the assistance i've had so for so thanks.

Cheers,

Steve

Answer (score 0):

Design your app as a whole and then break them into modules for easy development. This way you need not worry about integration part. You can have each functionality into different folders and not club them into a samefile/folder. These will make the overall project well organised.

However building independent modules and later integrating will lead to a bad design unless you have taken care of making those modules independent of each other.

Comment: Thanks guys, that makes a lot of sense.  I've started a new project with group folders and up till now i still have my hair.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

In some cases it is advisable to split the project to few mini projects.

I think that the main (and only?) case is code reuse.
One more reason might be hiding part of functionality from your client.
Meaning that if you have some module, or group of modules, that you are about to use in many applications then you might make your life easier by splitting these modules to a separate project(s).

In your case I wouldn't enter to this.
Focus on your learning and on the final project.
Splitting the project and then merging it may be longer than you think...

This is my opinion.